# Azure AD B2C MFA billing

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-billing

I want to switch to the new Azure AD External Identities billing detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/external-identities-pricing).

Looking at the pricing documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/external-identities/) it mentions the a flat fee of 0.03 $ for each SMS/Phone based MFA attempt is applied.

Was this also applicable on the previous pricing model of 1:5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

5:1 model vs MAU 50k free model are mutually exclusive. As soon as you enable MAU billing, 5:1 model stops being available/applicable to you

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The question is what fees for SMS/Phone authentication apply now for the 5:1 model for guests? This information I am missing.